# Woocommerce Product page add on checkbox and price

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

There is a website where we use WooCommerce infrastructure. I have products for which I use variations, and I want to make variations like the sample site below. When the customer selects the x option from the product with the x y z option, I want the number of names and the price of the checkbox field that I have determined on the product page. Can I do this with a ready-made plugin? Or do you have any suggestions? Thank you.
Sample site: https://www.bstkafes.com/index.php?page=urunler&urun-grup=k-26&urun=41

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin will help:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-extra-product-options/

From what I understand, you need to add extra options to products. Variations are different versions of the same product (e.g., white or black). In the example you presented it looks like you want to add extra features to do product.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-fields-for-variation/ This plugin does what I want but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can show different options and prices depending on which variation the user selects with this plugin: https://pluginrepublic.com/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-product-add-ons-ultimate/

The documentation for showing variation-specific fields is here:
https://pluginrepublic.com/documentation/variation-specific-fields/.

This lets you create different fields and only display them when certain variations are selected.